# I have a GitHub merging conflict and the conflict is showing that I have a teammates work included in mine yet I don’t

Tags: git, github, git-merge, conflict

I’m currently doing a project with a team of four on GitHub, so one teammate of mine created a feature branch and published it and it had code similar to what I wanted to do in my feature so I created a feature branch off his and went on to make necessary adjustments to it and published mine as well.
Well when I merge to the development branch where we merge all our features, I get a conflict showing files that were on the initial branch that I used to create mine.
What should I do?

Comment: Hello, you should try to rebase your branch on `develop`.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but are you sure you are merging the right branches? Have you made sure that you haven't committed anything on his branch?

Comment: Git doesn't really have branches (not in the sense *you're* thinking anyway): what Git has are *commits*. You started with your teammate's commits, so your commits depend on, and hence include, his commits. That's why you see his work included in yours. You'll need to make new and "improved" commits that don't depend on his: that's the rebase that @Floran mentioned above.

Comment: There are many options for making your new and ?improved? commits. You don't *have* to use `git rebase`. It's just that rebase is Git's power-tool method of doing mass quantities of commit-copying.